# C: Using functions from files within in the same project

Tags: c++, c, function, header, using

My question does not link to a direct example, but is more of a question as a whole.  When I was coding with C++, I found (after looking through some threads) that in order to use functions from different files that are in the same project, I would either need a header file.  So, for example, if I have the main function in a file called "main.cpp" and I wanted to use a function, "prob1()" in another file called "problem1.cpp", I would need to use a header file.

What is confusing me is why I do not have to worry about this for programming in C?  When I was programming in C, in order to use functions from different files, I could call the function directly.

Any help/explanation is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you feel the below answers solve your problem, you should accept one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your C compiler can implicitly declare the function, but you should be doing so yourself. If you turn up the warnings, you'll see something like:

```
file1.c: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘func_from_f2’
```

When *file1.c* is being *compiled*, this implicit *declaration* will be used to create an object file and then when *linking* you have to just hope that the function actually does exist and the declaration is correct so that the object files can be linked together successfully.

If not, the *linker* will give you an error somewhere along the lines of:

```
undefined reference to `func_from_f2'
```

You also don't necessarily need a header file, you can simply include the *declaration*/prototype of the function in your source file (the `#include` directive essentially does this for you). ie. the below will work fine without warnings:

**file1.c**

```
void func_from_f2(void);

int main(void)
{
   func_from_f2();

   return 0;
}
```

**file2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func_from_f2(void)
{
   puts("hello");
}
```

However, it's usually best practice that you do use a header file:

**file1.c**

```
#include "file2.h"

int main(void)
{
   func_from_f2();

   return 0;
}
```

**file2.h**

```
#ifndef FILE2_H
#define FILE2_H

void func_from_f2(void);

#endif
```

**file2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file2.h"

void func_from_f2(void)
{
   puts("hello");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear examples.  :D  I think I understand now.  I guess I'll look into headers and how exactly to format + use them.

Comment: You missed the one good practice that makes all of this worthwhile.  `#include "file2.h"` from inside `file2.c`, which will let the compiler see both the prototype and definition and verify that they match.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Oh dammit I did too.

Answer (score 2):

In C, the compiler will guess the correct prototype if you haven't provided one.  It very often guesses wrong, and then your program breaks.

Whether C or C++, it's always a good idea to put forward declarations in a header file that also gets `#include`d into the implementation file, where the compiler can check for mismatch.

Comment: Okay, gotchapon.  So basically, use headers to avoid any confusion and to ensure clear coding.  And if I am not mistaken, C++ enforces this, whereas C is a little more lenient.